# is it possible a link from iframe to affect the mother page/main page where iframe is displayed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a iframe that is included in another page (mother page).

```
<iframe name="commentsiframe" id="commentsiframe" onLoad="autoResize('commentsiframe');" width="100%" src="iframe.php" scrolling="no"  marginheight="0" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

What if i have a

```
<a href="#top">go top</a>
```

in the iframe page. And when i click on it i want to manipulate the main page/mother page and make it go on top.

I have no ideea if it is possible, but i assume if yes it must be javascript!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `target="_top"` or `target="_parent"` as attribute in the a-tag. Check out [here](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_a_target.asp)

Comment: Well, it will open the iframe page separately. And i dont want that

Answer (score 0):

If the domain of the iframe and mother page are the same , then its easy 
Use:

```
     window.parent.scrollTo(0,0);   //you can call any global function of the mother page
```

if the domain's are different , then its a bit difficult :
Refer to this question :
[Cross domain iframe issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393532/cross-domain-iframe-issue)