# Jquery: Unable find elements inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

i have page using iframe:

**page a.html**:

```
<div id="results">
  <iframe src="../b.aspx"></iframe>
</div>
```

now i want to get elements in iframe, so i try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            var tmp = $('#results iframe').contents().find('html').html();
            alert(tmp);
        });
</script>
```

but result return is: `<head></head><body></body>`, don't have content in head or body. i need a help

Comment: And what is actually inside of the iFrame? And what brwoser do you use? Are you calling this site with the file:// protocol?

Comment: @JayClaiton It can't be called with the `file://` protocol - it's an aspx file ;)

Comment: The access to the iframe may be restricted by the Cross-Origin-Policy

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey: so what i do?

Comment: If the frame's origin is on a different origin(domain) that your's you might not be able to access the frame. There is nothing you can do about it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393532/cross-domain-iframe-issue for more information.

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey Since he's using a relative URL for the iframe src, it must be in the same domain.

Answer (score 11):

Because your frame is not again loaded..

Try

```
$("#YOURFRAME").load(function (){
  var tmp = $('#results iframe').contents().find('html').html();
  alert(tmp);
});
```

Comment: Have you set an ID to your frame (called in this example YOURFRAME)

Comment: Can you give me a link please ?