# $('iframe').content(): Cannot get CORS passed

Tags: jquery, cors

I have an iframe on `http://mysite.dev:3000`, and a script on this page will set the iframe src attribute to `http://mysite.dev:5000/somepage.html`.

After the iframe gets loaded, I want to access its contents by using this script (on http://mysite.dev:3000):

```
$('iframe').load(function() {
    $('iframe').contents();
});
```

And I always get the error:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin.
```

Event though, the response header from `http://mysite.dev:5000/somepage.html` follows CORS guideline:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
access-control-allow-credentials:true
access-control-allow-headers:Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Accept
access-control-allow-methods:GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin:*
Cache-Control:public, max-age=0
```

I read several questions on SO and follow them, still it didn't work.

Comment: Where are you getting those header values from? Wireshark on the packet? Might be good to see the actual code sending the response.

Comment: It is set on server: res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', config.allowedDomains);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    next();

Answer (score 0):

The cors headers don't apply to iframes. You need to use the postMessage method to transfer data across different domains. see [Cross domain iframe issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393532/cross-domain-iframe-issue)