# cross domain resource sharing for my own domains into iframe

Tags: jquery

i have two domains.

1. www.application.com
2. www.storage.com

I have stored the html pages on the storage server i.e (www.storage.com). i have application hosted on www.application.com.

I wants to load the html page (www.storage.com) into iframe (www.application.com).

i want to access the content of the iframe using my application. but its not working.

its working if i upload my html files on the application server.

can anyone please help. how to resolve this issue???

Regards

Comment: did you understand what the problem is? why its not working?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393532/cross-domain-iframe-issue

Comment: as you have control over the second domain, you can do also CORS: http://enable-cors.org/server.html