# change label inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe in my web but labels are in English so I want to change to french using JavaScript 
the iframe is

```
<iframe src="https://nacampaigndirector.myconnectwise.net/serv/form/584188297a3e9a6447c4d307/58ee7ab77a3e9a22fc1d978c" scrolling="no" width="650px" height="600px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

and my code is of javascript is

```
<script>
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".col-sm-4 .control-label .ng-binding .fb-required");

x[0].innerHTML = "companies";
x[1].innerHTML = "Nom";
x[2].innerHTML = "Prenom";
x[3].innerHTML = "Telephone";
x[4].innerHTML = "Courriel";

</script>
```

but is not working my code

Comment: If the iframe is from a different domain, then you have no access to its content via JavaScript at all - Same Origin Policy.

Comment: yes it is in a different domain, I just created and use the html code

Comment: Then you can not do this. Suggest you go check with the provider of this service, whether they offer an option to change the language, perhaps via a GET parameter or something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross domain iframe issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393532/cross-domain-iframe-issue)