# Javascript Iframe not getting height calculated correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I am trying to display my iframe on any website like this one [HERE](http://be-a.co.uk/testframe.html) but for some reason the height is not calculated correctly. I get 8px on the style tag instead of 1000+ to display correctly that block.

```
<iframe id="iframe" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" style="width:100%; border:none" scrolling="no" src="http://newskillsacademy.co.uk/affiliates/iframe.php?&products_ids[]=55072&products_ids[]=51883&products_ids[]=49321&products_ids[]=48561&products_ids[]=48398&products_ids[]=46469&products_ids[]=44080&products_ids[]=43167&products_ids[]=42427&products_ids[]=41068&columns=3&aff_id=3"></iframe>
<script>
    var frame = document.getElementById('iframe');
    frame.style.height = 0; 
    frame.style.height = frame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px'; 
</script>
```

Comment: Try onload instead

Comment: @mplungjan issue is that it's like an iframe generator and needs to be placed on a second domain, the user places it, but I get also a cross browsing blocking, and not sure how to implement the solutions from here.

Comment: Across origins you may be SOL

Answer (score 2):

The line that sets the height (i.e. `frame.style.height = frame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';`) is likely run before the contents of the iframe have loaded. Thus in order to set the height properly, that code must be executed *after* the contents of the iframe have loaded.

One way to do this is to assign the [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) property to a function containing the code to set the height property:

```
var frame = document.getElementById('iframe');
frame.onload = function() {
  frame.style.height = frame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px'; 
}
```

See this demonstrated [here](http://embed.plnkr.co/B5HDOZEzWdCA5WPuFqCk/).

Also, the code attempts to fetch the iframe from the DOM as soon as the javascript executes. Depending on the location of the script tag/file (e.g. loaded via `<head>` or `<body>`) the DOM may not be ready. One solution to this is waiting for the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event. This can be achieved using [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) on `document`.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
  });
```

And because you initially tagged the question with jQuery, the [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready) method provides a shortcut to this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(event) {
  console.log("DOM is safe to manipulate");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Help appreciated, but http://be-a.co.uk/testframe.html it's now loading half and also get a cross-browser error which I searched on here, but don't understand how to implement it in my code. Note the iframe is on a different domain.

Comment: Do you have control over both domains? Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9393545/1575353) about a possible solution...

Comment: On the second domain won't have control (in this case I have), it's like a banner which the user generates and places on his site.

Comment: Trying to understand how to integrate my current javascript code on the iframe, but not sure where to place them.

Comment: Hmm well the iframe might not be the best solution. While this may be a bit of a hack, one possible approach is to use a server-side script (e.g. with PHP, python, RoR, c#, etc.) to pull in the contents from that URL (e.g. using cURL or a similar functions) and then return that HTML which could be altered...

Comment: And Could you help me based on my javascript code how to integrate it with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393532/cross-domain-iframe-issue/9393545#9393545. I am strugeling for hours.

Comment: If you have another question, please [post another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).