# How to Open iframe URL in new tab or window?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I want to open iframe URL in new tab.

Currently, my code opens iframe URL on same windows.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Start your code here -->

<div style="border: 2px solid #FFFFFF; overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 1058px;">
<iframe scrolling="no" src="http://www.lazada.com.my/unbeatable-deals/?spm=a2o4k.home.sku-feed-slider-with-banner_27936.31.lbj3BM&bid=my15da" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: 0px; height: 1186px; margin-top: -285px; margin-bottom: -105px; width: 100%;">
</iframe>
</div>

<!-- End your code here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The point of an iframe is to put the URL in a frame in the same window. Why are you using an iframe if you want it in a new window?

Comment: how do you want to open it in a new tab? is this something happen by a button click?  it should be the same as opening a new tab for a normal page but this time it will contain your iframe.
may be you need to create the iframe dynamically on the new tab, your question is not clear enough for me.

Comment: I want to bring a particular portion of website B into web site A. That's why I use above iframe method! Do you have any other method to do this?

Comment: i guess you need to use a href link to open a  new tab ! i suggest to create another page that contain only the iframe and a link or a photo in this page

Comment: Amr Elgarhy:  just click any URL inside iframe must open from new tab

Comment: "I want to bring a particular portion of website B into web site A.". Then you should include <iframe> in website A, the src is in website B.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to bring a particular portion of website B into web site A. That's why I use above iframe
>
> click any URL inside iframe must open from new tab

The link target is determined by the link itself, so in order to get the effect you want, you need to change the link element on *website B*.

That means you need access to edit *website B*. You cannot change the content (and link targets are content) of arbitrary third party websites.

You can either edit it directly, or dynamically change the links with JavaScript.

Since it is a different website, *website A* **cannot** directly access the link elements to change them. You would need to edit *website B* to include the JavaScript which modifies them (e.g. looping over `document.links` and setting the `target` on each). This could be triggered by [`postMessage` and friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393532/cross-domain-iframe-issue).

**If you cannot edit *website B* then this is impossible**.