# Targeting HTML inside iframe (need to redirect nVite form upon submission)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to redirect a page/run some js after an embedded nVite form is submitted on another page. The problem I'm having is there is no native solution through nVite to run some JS after a form submission. I also don't know a way to target any of the HTML inside of the iframe to check for changes. Does anyone know a way to target the HTML inside an iframe and or trigger JS after nVite from submission?

The form I'm trying to redirect can be found on [this page](https://www.machinery.ai/seattle) after clicking the registration button.

Comment: You can't target the HTML inside of the iframe.  This is a security feature on all modern browsers.

Comment: You'd have to communicate with the iframe via postmessage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not the owner of the website you are trying to access, you can't.

This is due to the Cross Domain policy.

If you are the owner, then try using postMessage, as described here:

[Cross domain iframe issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393532/cross-domain-iframe-issue)

Comment: Bummer, I kind of assumed this but my team is at the ropes end on this. I was hoping there was some sort of solution without help from the vendor. We've tried to reach out to the vendor but haven't heard back yet :(