# Same-origin policy error

Tags: html, iframe

I'd like to learn about Same-origin policy. There is a [site](http://qnimate.com/same-origin-policy-in-nutshell/) talking about it. But there have to be sth. wrong with the first example because i got an error `Illegal document.domain value`

Here is the problematic code:

The parent site located at http://www.qnimate.com/parent.html:

```
<iframe src="http://www.blog.qnimate.com/child.html" id="myIFrame"></iframe>
<script>
window.document.domain = "www.qnimate.com";//you also need to set the parent's document.domain variable
window.document.getElementById("myIFrame").contentWindow.document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";//this access is allowed by default
</script>
```

and iframe located at http://www.blog.qnimate.com/child.html:

```
<script>
window.document.domain = "www.qnimate.com"; //if we remove this line then the below line will not work and throw a same origin policy exception.
window.parent.document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only set `document.domain` to a superdomain of the current domain. You can remove components from the left-hand end.

The current domain is `www.blog.qnimate.com` so it can be set to `blog.qnimate.com` or `qnimate.com`.

You can't remove components in the middle, so you can't have `www.qnimate.com`.

---

To communicate across different origins through an iframe, use `postMessage` as described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393532/cross-domain-iframe-issue).

Comment: @Mulligun81 — Yes. The example code that you observed throws an error is not correct.