# Integrate an external element into my application - Javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I'm trying to integrate an external form into my application.

The form doesn't have a direct URL to it, so I'm trying to figure out how to do it.

First I've tried to put the homepage URL into an `<iframe>` , I was hoping to navigate with click() command inside the document of the iframe to arrive to the desired location, the problem was that the document of the iframe resulted to be empty.

I checked [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9393545/9365546) and unfortunately I don't have control over the framed site, so this road seems a dead end.

I'm looking for hints, I know there isn't a standard way to do this but as a JS beginner Is difficult taking first steps.

Thanks

Comment: This will not be possible if the resource loaded in the iframe is from a different domain. The browser protects against such scripting for the sake of security.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-origin stuff on the WWW usually requires the *explicit* cooperation of *both* sites.

If the document is empty, then the most likely reason is that [Display is forbidden by X-Frame-Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options).

If you can overcome that (you can't), then you'd hit the [permission denied to access property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393532/cross-domain-iframe-issue) problem.

Remote controlling how a browser behaves on a third-party website would be a security problem. You can't do it.