# Appending values to Iframe

Tags: iframe, append

I am trying to append new values to input from an iframe.
The iframe is a chart and what I am trying to append to the input is a different currency.

For example, instead of EURUSD, I would like to append GBPUSD and the chart refreshes automatically with the chart of GBPUSD.
You can also do this by entering the symbol name from the keyboard which requires some time and knowledge on the symbol of different trading instruments.

Here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ennygcnv/8/

```
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/ennygcnv/8/embed/"></script>
```

Comment: This goes against basic browser security. You cannot control iframe contents from an other domain. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9393532/643039)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross domain iframe issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393532/cross-domain-iframe-issue)