# getElementsByClassName from embedded web

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbyclassname

So,I embedded a website on my little project and I want a specific button on that embedded website to be clicked. I tried the

```js
function anyFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
  x[1].click();
  }
```

```html
<embed src="embeddedwebsite" style="width:100%;height:100%;"/>
```

and i got nothing. Maybe it was because the button i want to click is from an embedded website.
Is there any way to fixing the code.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The correct element for including another webpage is `<iframe>` so start by using that:

```
<iframe src="embeddedwebsite"></iframe>
```

You can then access content in it via:

```
document.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName("example");
```

… providing it is on the same origin.

Cross-origin frame access [has limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393532/cross-domain-iframe-issue) which you can work around via `postMessage`.