# Is there a way to make an IF statement based on a text string within an IFRAME?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently, I have a webpage that embeds the following IFRAME:

`<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/d/1P9DhWOHcl14Y7-P5wCxTm-sUceckGquPoOobO75XhvM/htmlembed/sheet?gid=630924986&single=true" frameborder="0" width="393px" height="385px" style="float:centre" id="MyFrame"></iframe>`

The contents of the cells are changed based on formulas. I am trying to find a way that would check if one of the cells (in this case, the cell containing "Foo" listed with a class of "S2" ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xdZm.png))) contains a string. Depending on the result, it would print different things to the console. For example:

```js
if <"Cell from inside the IFRAME with class S2"> = "stringtosearch"
  //found
  console.log("The cell contains stringtosearch!")
else
  //not found
  console.log("The cell does not contain stringtosearch. :( ")
```

Any help with a way of achieving this would be appreciated! I believe it can be done with jQuery, but I'm not sure on the best way to do it. I'm still new to JS.

**Note: I would need to embed this into a Chrome Extension, so I cannot use the option of pulling the Google Sheets API and searching it that way, as Chrome Extensions do not allow Inline Scripting.**

Thanks!

Comment: If you intend your parent page to interact with the DOM of a google sheet embedded in an iFrame then I suspect you'll be out of luck [Cross Domain Iframe Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393532/cross-domain-iframe-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Like @DarrenH eluded to in the comments, you have the problem of a cross-domain iframe. If your iframe were on the same domain, you could extract the `td` of a `table` like so:

**jQuery:**

```
var filteredContents = $('#MyFrame').contents().find('.s2');
if (filteredContents.text() == 'stringtosearch') {
   //found
   console.log("The cell contains stringtosearch!")
}
else {
   //not found
   console.log("The cell does not contain stringtosearch. :( ")
}
```

**Vanilla JavaScript:**

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("MyFrame");
var element = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (int i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
    if (element[i].classList.contains('s2')) {
       if (element[i].innerText == 'stringtosearch') {
           //found
           console.log("The cell contains stringtosearch!")
       }
       else {
           //not found
           console.log("The cell does not contain stringtosearch. :( ")
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer. The idea would be that the parent webpage is a published Chrome Extension. I'm not sure if that would classify as a cross-domain issue, because the Chrome Extension html page would be stored locally. I gave your answers a try. For the jQuery response, it always treated it as "Not Found", and for the Vanilla JS, it errored out with `Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of null`. I gather this means that I am hitting the cross-domain iframe issue. Is there any way of verifying this in the console, for example, to be sure? Thanks!