# document.getElementsByTagName doesn't work inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, getelementsbytagname

I have a simple html document containing an iframe. In this iframe there is a wikipedia page. For now, I'm just trying to take the title of the wikipedia page and to output it into the log console.
Here's the code I'm using :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>
    <head>  <!-- Tout ce qui est pas dans le contenu -->
        <title> example</title>
        
    </head>
    
    <body>

        <h1>A Web Page</h1>

        <script>
            const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
            iframe.src = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics";
            iframe.height = 800;
            iframe.width = 900;
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
            var elmnt = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("H1");
            console.log("the title is " + elmnt[0]);

        </script>
          
    </body>
</html>
```

I expect to get "the title is Mathematics" in the console from this example, but instead I get, "the title is undefined". I checked and "Mathematics" is indeed inside a h1 tag on wikipedia, so I don't understand the issue here.

Comment: You're being defeated by the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: No it doesn't work because the iFrames are independent

Comment: @Mitya I'm sorry I didn't see the domain issue here. Your comment / suggestion is correct. I will remove my first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a timing issue.

You aren't waiting for the document to load, so the HTML hasn't been parsed and the element doesn't exist yet.

```
iframe.addEventListener("load", () => {
    var elmnt = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("H1");
    console.log("the title is " + elmnt[0]);              
})
```

… solves that problem and you promptly run into [the cross-origin security limits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393532/cross-domain-iframe-issue) instead.