# Getting data on click from iframe CORS

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm currently working on an iframe for clients
It's juste a carrousel with pictures if the user clicks on a picture I need to display the content in full screen with some navigation (next, previous)

Since I never worked with CORS before, I'm getting a hard time figuring how to pass my data from the iframe to the client website :/

Here's a simplified version of the code
Iframe:

```
<div class="carrousel">
    <div class="carrousel_item">
        <img data_id="0">
    </div>
    <div class="carrousel_item">
        <img data_id="1">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var gallery = { 0: url1, 1: url2}
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.carrousel.carrousel_item img').on('click', function(){
            var data = { data: gallery, last_iterator: jQuery(this).data('id')}
            var event = new CustomEvent('display_post', { detail: data })
            return window.parent.document.dispatchEvent(event)
        }
    })
</script>
```

ScriptJS:

```
<script>
    window.document.addEventListener('display_post', handleEvent, false)
    function handleEvent(e) {
        console.log(e.detail)
        challenge_marque_explorer = data['data'] // image list
        last_iterator = data['last_iterator'] // which image is displayed
        display_post_details() // fill an overlay display with the image and nav arrow
    }
</script>
```

If I try it on my domain, everything's is fine
But on an other domain I get error's (this one return :  Uncaught DOMException: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object)

Edit:
After 1 hour making close to no progress, I noticed my FTP soft wasn't succeeding in sending the script, now my code works
Here's my working code using postMessage

iFrame:

```
    var gallery = { 0: url, 1: url}
    var origin

    window.onmessage = function(event) {
        origin = event.origin
    };
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.carrousel.carrousel_item img').on('click', function(){
            var data = { data: challenge_marque_explorer, last_iterator: i, dest: last_dest, page: 0 }
            return window.parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data),origin);
        }
    })
```

The script for the parent page:

```
    window.onmessage = function(event) {
      console.log(event.data)
    };
    jQuery('#gallery_iframe').load(function(){
        document.getElementById('gallery_iframe').contentWindow.postMessage('','*');
    })
```

Thanks guys for your time and help :)

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer, but this is where I'd use [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) rather than an event. `postMessage` doesn't have same origin restrictions. Be sure to check `origin` at both ends yourself to ensure you only process appropriate messages. Happy coding!

Comment: *“the code is not working”* isn’t a problem description with enough detail for anybody here to be able to answer. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and update the question. What are the exact errors he browser is logging in the devtools console when you try your code?

Comment: Duplicate — http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393532/cross-domain-iframe-issue  — (CORS is not involved here)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I tried with post message, but I don't get any reaction from my clic, nothing in the console and none of my alerts got triggered :/

Comment: @sebe - It sounds like you're probably not quite using `postMessage` correctly. Your best bet here is to do (even) more research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and see if you can figure out why it's not working. ***If*** you do that but still get stuck and can't get unstuck, post a question with a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Happy coding!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Took me 1hour to notice fileZilla only succeed 10 push on the script but 50 on the iframe ... :(
Well in the end using postMessage did the trick, I'm just not sure if I've done it in a clean way (honestly it doesn't look like so since I'm using the "load" function), but at least it works :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're stuck and don't see any progress in one of your script, try using 'alert()' to do a quick check on wether or not your file was really updated

Also think about checking the cache, don't loose time and patience due to a file that wasn't sending