# Get the url from frame redirection

Tags: javascript, redirect, frameset

I did a frame redirection to redirect subdomain.domain1.com to domain2.com. It works well ie I got "subdomain.domain1.com" in the address bar and the domain2.com is well displayed. However, I try to get the url in js code.

```
console.log(window.location.href);
```

This line show me "domain2.com" but it would be "subdomain.domain1.com". How to get that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window` refers to the current page.

If you want the URL of the parent frame then you would need to go to `window.parent`.

At that point you'll run into a cross-origin error. If you controlled the parent then you could use [postMessage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393532/cross-domain-iframe-issue) to pass the data through.

Since you are using a frame redirection, that seems unlikely though. Generally this is one of many limitations with frame based redirection that mean you should generally avoid that approach in the first place.

Comment: ok thanks. Indeed, I Try "window.parent" but I got cross-origin error... Is there alternative to frame redirection to have "subdomain.domain1.com" in the address bar and "domain2.com" displayed without ssl certificate error ? Because I did this redirection to avoid NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error.

Comment: Get a certificate that supports subdomain.domain1.com

Comment: How to do that ? Can we add 2 certificates for one domain ?

Comment: https://sectigostore.com/page/one-ssl-certificate-for-multiple-domains/#:~:text=You%20absolutely%20can%20use%20one,subdomains%20in%20addition%20to%20domains.&text=For%20securing%20multiple%20domains%20with,multi%20domain%20wildcard%20SSL%20certificate.