# Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://127.0.0.1:4100" from accessing a cross-origin frame - REACT JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have and Iframe in a react component which loads a pdf file on click of button from an external url (My Api endpoint with port `8000`), After It's loaded successfully, I want to print the content of that Iframe, But getting and error

Here is my react component

```
import React from 'react'

const pageCont = () =>{
   return(
     <div>
         <iframe id='pdfp' name='pdfp' src='http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/ebook.pdf'></iframe>
         <button onClick={()=>{
            document.getElementById("pdfp").contentWindow.focus()
            document.getElementById("pdfp").contentWindow.print()}
          }>
Print Iframe
        </button>
    </div>
    )
}
export default pageCont;
```

`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://127.0.0.1:4100" from accessing a cross-origin frame`

I am making Request from front end which has a url of `127.0.0.1:4100` . I feel this error is due to the fact that the Iframe source and request origin has different protocols.

Comment: Please [**search**](/search?q=Blocked+a+frame+with+origin+from+accessing+a+cross-origin+frame) before posting and if you post anyway, say why those previous answers didn't solve your problem. More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Answer (score 0):

You can't access cross-origin iframes directly.

[There are methods to communicate, through iframes, between HTML documents on different origins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393532/cross-domain-iframe-issue) but they don't apply here since you are loading a PDF.

A few approaches you could take for dealing with this are:

- Use the same origin for both documents
- Convert the PDF to HTML
- Fetch the HTML with Ajax (you'll need CORS) and then render it with something like Mozilla's PDF.js