# CORS error when trying to scroll in a PDF iframe Electron

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, electron, cross-domain

How can you read and change the x / y coordinates of a PDF in an iframe, my iframe looks like this: `<iframe id="pdf-interface" class="pdf-interface" src=path></iframe>` where `path` is the local path to the PDF file.
All attempts I've tried until now failed with the error message: `Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://127.0.0.1:8080" from accessing a cross-origin frame`.
Is there any way to fix this or an alternative way of doing this?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22362008/access-to-iframe-contents-of-local-file/39685594#39685594

Comment: Serve the pdf from your localhost so origins are the same

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll look into the ressources, should've used the stackoverflow search engine not only google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access cross-origin iframes directly.

Read more about it on Quentin's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66139466/7942242

And Willy Wonka's answer might interest you as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/39685594/7942242 which has a reference about how to bypass Same Origin Policy.

Comment: I'll look into it, shame that there is no way to at least read out the page number of a pdf, this makes an iframe for PDFs kind of useless in my opinion