# Is it possible for JavaScript to access external files locally?

Tags: javascript, html, object, svg, local

I want to access attributes of my svg:

`<object id="mainIcon" type="image/svg+xml" data="icons/ribbon.svg"></object>`

I read that it should be possible with `documentElement` or `getSVGDocument`, but both of them return `null`. Further searching reveals that they don't work locally only by web server... All answers I seem to find seem to be solely concerned with web servers and offer no local solutions.

Comment: *"All answers I seem to find seem to be solely concerned with web servers and offer no local solutions."* That's because browsers behave in slightly arcane and varying ways when dealing with "local" resources (resources identified by `file://` URIs). Your best bet is almost always to use a local webserver and serve from `http://localhost` URIs instead. Installing a local web server is quite easy in most environments.

Comment: [This is related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393532/cross-domain-iframe-issue) but I've no idea if you can persuade postMessage to work from a pure SVG document.

Comment: No, browsers security models generally don't permit this. Use a web server if you want to develop web pages.

Comment: @Quentin [yes you could](https://jsfiddle.net/o3u95yeb/), though there is an interop' issue here with FF where they don't allow the use of <object>'s WindowProxy on cross-origin docs. (Using an <iframe> instead would workaround that, and since <object> is probably gonna be deprecated, <iframe> should anyway be preferred).