# Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs

My website [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com)

I am using iframe in [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) with `<iframe src="www.xyz.com"></iframe>`

I am facing the below issue

Issue :

> Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.

How to solve the issue with only using source code (Angularjs(V 1.X), Javascript, jQuery, HTML), without touching browser settings manually.

Is there any way to change browser settings(set allow cookies) via source code or server side settings?

[www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) , [www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com) both website localstorage used indivudually, I am not accessing localstorage from one website to other.

When i open the iframe page i am facing the issue "Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cross domain iframe issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393532/cross-domain-iframe-issue)

Comment: Are you trying to access the localStorage from site abc in the website in the iframe (xyz)?

Comment: I am using localStorage here "www.xyz.com", not trying to access "www.abc.com"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393532/cross-domain-iframe-issue   This one not helped me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question, you maybe change your chrome cookie setting

[this is the document link](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-read-the-localstorage-property-from-window-access-is-denied-for-this-document/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

The following snippet accesses the current domain's local `Storage` object and adds a data item to it using `Storage.setItem()`.

```
 localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
```

The syntax for reading the localStorage item is as follows:

```
const cat = localStorage.getItem('myCat');
```

Kind refer to the following [documentation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#dom-localstorage-dev)