# JS how to access element with id beginning with underscore "_"?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a kind-of click-redirect (user clicks on span, another element gets `.click()`ed programatically) on the YouTube subscribe button embedded in my webpage.
The markup is (simplified) the following after Google's script runs over the initial markup:

```html
<!-- The property `otherproperties="notmentionedhere"` is a placeholder for the other properties those elements have, some of those properties vary with each load of the page. -->
<div id="___ytsubscribe_0" otherproperties="notmentionedhere">
    <iframe otherproperties="notmentionedhere">
        #document <!-- This element doesn't really exist, it's Firefox's way of representing the markup inside the iFramed page in DevTools -->
            <!--some other elements-->
                <button data-channel-external-id="UCO6YRllfXXIe2lPWenjmfPw" otherproperties="notmentionedhere"><!-- some other elements /--></button>
            <!--/some other elements-->
</div>
```

My current code in the onlick property of the span to click that button:

```js
document.getElementById('___ytsubscribe_0').querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.document.querySelector('button[data-channel-external-id=UCO6YRllfXXIe2lPWenjmfPw]').click();
```

The problem I have is that an element's ID property must begin with a letter but the YouTube subscribe button's container's ID begins with three underscores.

Here's a code snippet that shows the actual markup plus my code:

```html
<!-- You might have to copy the markup into an own HTML document on your computer to see it in action, at least for me it always fails on load with a "SecurityError: Document.cookie getter: Forbidden in a sandboxed document without the 'allow-same-origin' flag."... -->
<span onclick="document.getElementById('___ytsubscribe_0').querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.document.querySelector('button[data-channel-external-id=UCO6YRllfXXIe2lPWenjmfPw]').click();">Click here to subscribe!</span>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<div class="g-ytsubscribe" id="yt-sub-dark" data-channelid="UCO6YRllfXXIe2lPWenjmfPw" data-layout="full" data-theme="dark" data-count="default"></div>
```

Note: [it's a seperate question to click on a button inside a CrossOrigin-iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393532/cross-domain-iframe-issue). This question is just about finding the  whose id begins with underscore.

Comment: I'm not sure I've fully understood but, if you have a web page with the embedded button you could use the browser's inspector to fish out a valid alternative selector from the copy menu for the button.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

See the snippet below.

```js
const ytsubdiv = document.querySelector('#___ytsubscribe_0')

console.log(ytsubdiv)
```

```html
<div id="___ytsubscribe_0" otherproperties="notmentionedhere">
  <iframe otherproperties="notmentionedhere">
        #document <!-- This element doesn't really exist, it's Firefox's way of representing the markup inside the iFramed page in DevTools -->
            <!--some other elements-->
                <button data-channel-external-id="UCO6YRllfXXIe2lPWenjmfPw" otherproperties="notmentionedhere"><!-- some other elements /--></button>
            <!--/some other elements-->
            </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: I just noticed that the YT-sub-button-iframe a CrossOrigin-resource is, is it possible to still dispatch a click on the button inside? EDIT: I'll check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393532/cross-domain-iframe-issue for that...