# How to extract user code from EXTERNAL IDE-iframe in my wordpress site?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, iframe

I am developing a WordPress website for an IT school that is controlled by me.
I use **external** IDE iframe on my website. I would like to extract the student's code from `iframe` IDE and save it in my WP database.
Next time when a student wants to return to a page, I would like to extract his code from my database, and then replace the skeleton code with his code.

```js
    function extractIframeContent() {
      var iframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
      var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
      var content = iframeDoc.documentElement.innerHTML;
      console.log("content:" + content);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Extract Content from Iframe</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="myIframe" src="https://trinket.io/embed/python3/4e8cf39550" width="100%" height="356" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" allowfullscreen allow="cross-origin-isolated"></iframe>
<button onclick="extractIframeContent()">Extract Content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

As a result, I take:
`Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:63343" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`
It occurs when I try to access the content of an iframe from a **different origin (domain)** using JavaScript. This error is a result of the Same-Origin Policy security restriction.

A moderator marked this question as a **[duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393532/cross-domain-iframe-issue)**.
I don't agree because answers on that post assume `only if you have control for both sites`. **In my case, I control only a website, not iframe src.**

I found out that an iframe sends a request to its server. How can I read and replace the payload of it? Maybe you can suggest another workaround for it?

I don't understand why I can't extract the data that I have inserted?!
Help me!